# Photos-style ImageView with black bars

Tags: android, android-imageview

I would like to display an `ImageView` similar to how Google's Photos app does: with black bars on the top and bottom, in case the photo does not fill the entire screen.

Below is my current layout for the `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentImageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```

I originally had the width and height set to `match_parent` so it would fill the entire screen, but this led to the image being stretched and some of the sides were cut off. Using `wrap_content`, none of the image is cut off, but it does not fill the entire page and there is blank whitespace, as you can see below.

How can I center the image between two black bars, similar to how the Photos app does it?

Thank you!

**Image in my app (with transparent actionbar overlay, similar to Photos):**

[image: My app]

**Similar image in the Google Photos app:**

[image: Photos app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match_parent` for the height, but switch the scaleType to `centerInside`. See the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). This will ensure that the image aspect ratio is preserved and that none of the image is truncated. Set the background of the ImageView to black to show the black bars top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using android 5 material design why not Customize the Status Bar and Actoin Bar with black color, for the Action bar(using color primary attribute) and Status bar(using color primary dark attribute). If you have no clue about what i am talking please refer this link it explains it in detail.
https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html